# Should class structure match table structure in OOP?

Tags: java, database, oop

I have an issue. I would like to ask your help.

For example, I have two tables:
users(id, first_name, last_name)
answers(id, user_id, content)

In creating my class Answer, should it contain an object User or just a userId field ?

In the first case, I'll have the User fields ready at hand, but it will require me to browse the table users when I'm fetching an answer from the answers table.

In the second case, each time I have a need for the user's information, I'll have to fetch them from the users table.

This is just a simple example. What approach should I take in a complexe project with intertwining tables and lots of foreign keys.

Edit:

I'm not using any ORMs.

Comment: No. Next question?

Comment: are you using any ORM Tool to interact with DB?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no concerning what approach?

Comment: @umashankar no i'm not using any ORMs

Comment: A lot of developers would use an ORM like Hibernate to help with this. Hibernate is popular in the Java world. It can fetch a virtual copy of the related objects, but some people don't like the fact that this hides details from the developer about how many times the database is hit. Another options is something like [jooQ](http://www.jooq.org/). I personally would change my approach on a case-by-case basis. Sometimes you want to fetch related objects automatically, sometimes not.

Comment: @Elyes, the class is not required to match table structure. In most cases, it cannot do that even, because a row of relational table store is not something which can be easily represented with a static class.

Comment: The answer must obviously be "No, the structure does not have to match".

You don't even need to know anything about databases or OOP to see that: suppose that the structure of objects matched the structure of rows exactly. What could you *possibly* do with these objects, except reimplement your own slow & buggy version of a database?

Comment: If I understand you, then the class User should have a List<Answer> and the class Answer a User object which itself has a list of all their answers. Doesn't this create a loop?

Answer (score 2):

No, in general, classes in a well-designed object-oriented program do not mirror tables you find in a relational database. How the data is structured and stored is an "implementation detail" that an object should generally hide from its customers.

Each object should provide a specific service and, internally, may collaborate with other objects to fulfill its responsibilities.  An object's API should hide the existence of its component parts and expose a simpler abstraction to its peers.

Try to work out what services your system provides and how to divvy up those responsibilities among objects.

Comment: so imagine that a user has more than one answer related to them. Does that translate into a List<Answer> in the User class ?

Comment: Users and answers aren't services / responsibilities in the system.

Answer (score -1):

If not using an ORM, you may do what ever you find more practical, but keeping similar or identical names will help with basic search and principle of least surprise:

`firstname -> getFirstname` ...

For the structure it all depends on what you intend to do with the data, so it is hard to tell.
The Java Objects do not need to mirror the database, this is why using Object Relational Mapping exists, because those are two different worlds.

IMHO the objects which carry data should be plain and simple (no business logic in getters), but they may check validity of values during construction so that you can trust the data later on (assert notBlank, >= 0, ...)

First simple code that does the job, then try to rewrite it ideally for both performance and maintenability.

Comment: So downvotes without any comment, is that constructive ? What is that good for ?

Comment: What I said is perfectly valid, do not worry too much about OOP, keep it simple and make it work. OOP is just a tool, keep that in mind.